# Getting TypeError When Trying To Write To A File And Append It To a Zip folder at same time

Tags: python, zip

I want to write some information to a text file and after my loop is done writing information to this text file, throw that file to a zip folder. Here's what I have right now.

```
import zipfile

    file_names = ['oranges.txt', 'lemonade.txt', 'mango.txt']

    for file in file_names:

        text_file_name = f"{file}.txt"
        counter = 1

        zf = zipfile.ZipFile('food_data.zip', "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        response = requests.get(f"api.farmers.com?page={counter}")

        if response.json != []:
            with ZipFile("food_data.zip", "w") as zip:
                with zip.open(file, "w") as f:
                    f.write("Confirmed API is working!")
                    counter += 1
                    
           zf.writestr(file_name, json.dumps(response.json()))
    >>>>  **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**
            

I've tried to add "rb" to the write mode in `ZipFile("food_data.zip", "w") as zip:` but then I get the error message `ValueError: ZipFile requires mode 'r', 'w', 'x', or 'a'`
```

This is the documentation for ZipFile that I was reading about: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

```
file = 'file.txt'

zipfile.ZipFile('food_data.zip', "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.writestr(file, "Hello! Confirmed that API is working!")
zf.close()
```

Comment: Ahh... unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Made an edit, try again please.

Comment: I think writing the file to the zip rather than a string will fix the value error.

Comment: Yeah that did end up fixing the type error but I need to figure out how to incorporate that into my loop. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you update the question with the required imports I'll take a stab at the loop.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243723/discussion-between-captain-caveman-and-superdummy).

Comment: I'm getting the error: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL api.farmers.com?page=1

Comment: Yeah so that API was just something I made up on the fly lol. The API I'm trying to target is a private one that needs an API key to authenticate to.

Comment: Please make sure to post reproducible code next time. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Good point. Thanks for headsup on that. I'll make sure to be more careful next time.